# Back to Top link to only show on non-mobile devices

Tags: jquery, mobile, scroll

We have some simple JQuery that shows a back to top link when the user scrolls down to a certain page (and beyond) of the page.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
    }
});
$('.scrollup').click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
    return false;
});
```

How can we trigger this so it only shows on the desktop version, and not mobile?

I tried wrapping it in:

```
if($(window).width() >= 480)
```

for example, but it still shows?

Answer (score 0):

simple css solution is

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.scrollup{display:none!important;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is **no proper way using CSS** to determine whether someone is on a mobile or not. That requires javascript and detection of userAgents.

Quick Solution:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') != -1 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Blackberry') != -1 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1) {
   $('.scrollup').hide();
}
```

The more efficient solution would be **feature detection**:

Check out these articles for more info:

http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/detect-browser/

http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/feature-detection-state-of-the-art-browser-scripting